# Update in Codeigniter for Beginner

Tags: codeigniter

Can anyone help me to update in Codeigniter?

This is my model code:

```
function update($data,$userid)
{
    $data = array(
               'dob' => $dob,
               'sex' => $sex,              
    );

    $this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
    $this->db->update('profile', $data); 
}
```

Comment: What will be the controller for this

Comment: it looks about right - assuming $dob and $sex are populated. Do you get them with $this->input->post() or are they in the $data array, in which case you need to replace it with $data['dob'] and $data['sex']

Comment: as this is my controller function insertbasicinfo()
 {
   $this->load->model('info_model');
   $userid=$this->session->userdata('userID');
   $data = array( 
                    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
                    'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
              'languages' => $this->input->post('languages'),
                    
                     );

      $dat['basicinfo']=$this->info_model->insertbasicinfo($data,$userid);
      $this->load->view('basicinfo',$dat);
      }

Comment: ok, then if all post data is in post, then replacing $dob with $data['dob'] and $sex with $data['sex'] should work - though unnecessary if you already are passed the variables into the data array. You could technically just insert $data as received - though you want to process the variables first

Comment: i did not understand please you write on new page, in model or in controller i write $data['dob']

Comment: assuming your controller has already put all necessary variables in the data array, then all you need in the model is the where clause and the update call. In other words, in the model, you are trying to create the data array a second time with invalid variables $dob and $sex - which are un-initialized in the model. They are however already initialized in the $data array from your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$where = array('id'=>'10','email'=>'dude@dude.com');
$data = array('username'=>'lol');

function update($data,$where){
    foreach($where as $key=>$value){
        $this->db->where($key,$value);
    }
    $this->db->update('users',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are passing dob and sex via the data variable in the function you're just trying to access those incorrectly.

```
function update($data,$userid)
{
    $data = array(
               'dob' => $data['dob'],
               'sex' => $data['sex'],              
    );

    $this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
    $this->db->update('profile', $data); 
}
```

And for that matter if that is all that's in that data variable you can lose the first part entirely since it is really just replicating what you already have.

```
function update($data,$userid)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
    $this->db->update('profile', $data); 
}
```